# How to find the Skolem form of the following formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm confused about finding a Skolem form of the following formula:

F = $(\forall x)(P(x)\rightarrow(\forall y)((\forall z)Q(z,y)\rightarrow\neg(\forall z)R(y,z)))$

So following the algorithm I've done these transformations:

F = $(\forall x)(\neg P(x)\vee(\forall y)((\exists z)\neg Q(z,y)\vee(\exists z)\neg R(y,z)))$

= $(\forall x)(\neg P(x)\vee(\forall y)((\exists z)\neg Q(z,y)\vee(\exists m)\neg R(y,m)))$

= $(\forall x)(\forall y)(\neg P(x)\vee(\neg Q(f(x,y),y)\vee\neg R(y,g(x,y))))$

= $\neg P(x)\vee(\neg Q(f(x,y),y)\vee\neg R(y,g(x,y)))$

But the solution on the textbook gives a different answer which is:

F = $(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(\forall v)(\neg P(x)\vee\neg Q(z,y)\vee\neg R(y,v)))$

= $\neg P(x)\vee\neg Q(z,y) \vee \neg R(y,v)$

I can't quite understand. What's wrong with my own solution? And why here the $z$ is replaced with a constant instead of a function like $g(x,y)$ or $f(x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct, the book's solution got wrong at the first step:
\begin{align}
F=&\forall x\forall y\exists z\exists v(\lnot P(x)\lor(\lnot Q(z,y)\lor\lnot R(y,v)))\\
\neq&\forall x\forall y\forall z\forall v(\lnot P(x)\lor(\lnot Q(z,y)\lor\lnot R(y,v)))
\end{align}
Clearly, these two prenex normal forms are not equivalent.

Comment: I' m thinking about a question. Do we really need to remove the implications? If the implications are allowed to keep in the final result, then we can reach the book's solution. Because we don't remove the implications, there is no existential quantifiers appeared.

Comment: @Chor No, even without removing the implication, the step that moves out those universal quantifiers of $z,v$ still can't be justified, I think it's just a typo of the book.

Answer (score 0):

I verified Manx's previous result and it's correct. According to the implication rule during prenex normal form conversion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication), from your first sentence F:

F = $\forall x \forall y [P(x) \rightarrow (\forall z Q(z,y) \rightarrow \neg \forall v R(y,v))]$

F = $\forall x \forall y [P(x) \rightarrow (\neg \forall z Q(z,y) \lor \neg \forall v R(y,v))]$

F = $\forall x \forall y [P(x) \rightarrow (\neg (\forall z Q(z,y) \land \forall v R(y,v)))]$

F = $\forall x \forall y [P(x) \rightarrow (\neg \forall z \forall v (Q(z,y) \land R(y,v)))]$

F = $\forall x \forall y [\neg P(x) \lor (\neg \forall z \forall v (Q(z,y) \land R(y,v)))]$

F = $\forall x \forall y [\neg P(x) \lor \exists z \exists v \neg (Q(z,y) \land R(y,v))]$

F = $\forall x \forall y \exists z \exists v [\neg P(x) \lor \neg (Q(z,y) \land R(y,v))]$

F = $\forall x \forall y \exists z \exists v [\neg P(x) \lor (\neg Q(z,y) \lor \neg R(y,v))]$